# ERC721 - mass ownerOf request(or another way get all TokenIDs on address)

Tags: erc-721, nft, nethereum

I use nethereum for get ownerOf NFT ids

```
[Function("ownerOf", "address")]
public class OwnerOfFunction : FunctionMessage
{
    [Parameter("uint256", "_tokenId", 1)]
    public uint TokenID { get; set; }
}

public void IsOwnerOfToken()
{
    var web3 = new Nethereum.Web3.Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/7238211010344719ad14a89db874158c");

    string contractAddress = "0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88";

    var ownerOfFunctionMessage = new OwnerOfFunction()
    {
        TokenID = 99999,
    };

    var ownerOfHandler = web3.Eth.GetContractQueryHandler<OwnerOfFunction>();
    var ownerAddress = ownerOfHandler.QueryAsync<string>(contractAddress, ownerOfFunctionMessage).Result;
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(ownerAddress);
}
```

But i want get all tokenIds on current current.

I can use really brute way,  ownerOf of EVERY tokenId, from zero to until get this exception

```
RpcResponseException: execution reverted: ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token
```

this message appears when TokenID more than token counts.

But maybe exist more elegant way? Maybe i can something like this?

```
var owners = web3.Eth.GetContractQueryHandler<OwnerOfFunction>(0, "latest");
```

Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is not possible in a generic way.

Here is an example ERC-721 implementation that you cannot query to get all tokens using any reasonable method.

```
contract ERC721 is iERC721, iERC165 {
    function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256) {
        if (_owner == address(0x01)) return 2;
        return 0;
    }

    function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address) {
        if (sha3(_tokenId) == 0x0) return 0x01;
        revert();
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) external payable {
        revert();
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable {
        revert();
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable {
        revert();
    }

    function approve(address _approved, uint256 _tokenId) external payable {
        revert();
    }

    function setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved) external {
        revert();
    }

    function getApproved(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address) {
        return address(0x0);
    }

    function isApprovedForAll(address _owner, address _operator) external view returns (bool) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The implementation is valid by the specification, but the only way you can find which token(s) have an owner is by finding a 256-bit number that hashes to zero. Good luck. I assert that there are exactly two such numbers that exist.

Because what you want is not possible, instead you'll have to settle for a practical approach:

- Listen to events
- Hope that tokens IDs are sequential and use your approach
- Use the NFT enumeration extension